# Run main several times of wasm in browser

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I have a C CLI program that I compiled to wasm with Emscripten. I'm trying to run that program each time a button is pressed, reading from a textbox into stdin and from stdout to another textbox. However, I can only call `Module.callMain()` successfully once. Each subsequent invocation does not execute. How to properly setup this?

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="input" rows="8"></textarea>
    <button onclick="exec()">run</button>
    <textarea id="output" rows="8"></textarea>
    <script>
      var input_box = document.getElementById('input');
      var input_text = "";
      let i = 0;

      var Module = {
        noInitialRun: true,
        noExitRuntime: true,
        print: (function() {
          var element = document.getElementById('output');
          if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache
          return (...args) => {
            var text = args.join(' ');
            console.log(text);
            if (element) {
              element.value += text + "\n";
              element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
            }
          };
        })(),
        stdin: (function() {
          return () => {
            if (i >= input_text.length) {
              return null;
            } else {
              return input_text.charCodeAt(i++);
            }
          };
          })(),
        };

      function exec() {
        console.log(i);
        i = 0;
        input_text = input_box.value;
        console.log(input_text);

        Module.callMain([]);
      }
    </script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `.js` file is the one output from emscripten without modifications.
Here are the flags used to compile:

```bash
-s 'EXIT_RUNTIME=0' -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='[\"callMain\",\"run\"]' -s ENVIRONMENT=web
```

Comment: The event listener used to grab input may be relevant. Please share the code that includes that, or a minimal example that will help reproduce the issue.